# Is this UI layout possible with Android (java based)?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm a complete newbie to Android but played with the idea to port an app to Android to learn it. After doing some first steps with the SDK and looking at the UI samples, I'm still unsure whether the particular ui layout of this conference schedule/timetable app you can see here

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dJ5rDybL8es

is possible with Android.

I particular, the layout consists of something like a table with a fixed column on the left showing the times, which is always visible, and a column to the right which shows sessions that take place in the room displayed at the columns top.
By swiping left/right on the right column, you can change the room and see the corresponding session.
(In landscape view all three rooms are shown next to each other, but I'm particularly interested in that scroller possibility of the portrait layout)

I've seen that there is a ViewFlipper class, but I'm unsure whether that could scroll parts of the screen (the right "column" in my example) and also if by swiping.

I would be very happy if someone with Android experience could give me some advice with which view elements I can replicate that layout on Android, if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In its very simplest form you're gonna want a ScrollView on the left, and then a SwipeView on the right, and then within that SwipeView you're gonna want another ScrollView.

I'd consider not using a ScrollView though, but instead using a ListView so that only the elements in view are actually loaded in.

ScrollView is part of the Android SDK.

SwipeView is a nice little addition to the Android SDK, have some links:

http://jasonfry.co.uk/?id=23

http://jasonfry.co.uk/?id=24

https://jasonfry.co.uk/blog/android-swipeview-update/

(disclaimer, I made SwipeView...;)

Here is some information about ListView:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html

Have a look in the API demos app that you should have downloaded with the SDK for how to use a ListView (as well as a lot of other very useful things...)

The layout in the video is definitely possible! Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! But if I use a ListView or ScrollView on the left then the times column would scroll independently, no? I would want to have them scroll together, both the ListView and the Swipeview, as the times column indicates when the session start. Currently I have no idea how to connect both, but I probably have overlooked something.

Comment: true they would scroll independently by default, but you could implement an onscrolllistener on one and get it to scroll the other manually and vice versa. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html